# Cant ping LAN devices with Pfsense and OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

I am currently doing a test for our OpenVPN setup through Pfsense, we have 2 Pfsense running on the network,

1. For the default gateway of the LAN Network as Main Firewall.
2. For the OpenVPN Clients as a secondary Firewall.

Based on my Test, I successfully Connect the OpenVPN client to the Pfsense however I can't ping the LAN devices except for the OpenVPN Pfsense LAN interface which is 192.168.0.4. right now our LAN devices are pointing to 192.168.0.1 which is the Main pfsense. But when I tried to change the default gateway with one of the LAN devices I can receive a reply when I ping from the OpenVPN client. I also tried adding a static route to the main pfsense and the ISP modem for the OpenVPN Tunnel Network 192.168.3.0/24 and received no reply when pinging from the OpenVPN client.

I would like to ask if putting a static route is possible? or am I missing any configuration? like firewall rules or NAT? or another way?

This is the Topology of the setup:

[image: setuptopology]

Answer (score 0):

Routing from the default should need to be modified. You will have to create a NAT rule to allow the OpenVPN ports.